# Is there another way to check if an array is empty

Tags: c#, arrays, int

I've added a condition that checks if an array is empty and automatically set an integer to larger than the size of the array since it's empty, but i get an "Index was outside the bounds of the array." mesage instead

```
    public static bool hurdleJump(int[] hurdles, int jumpHeight)
    {
        int max = hurdles[0];

        if (hurdles == null && hurdles.Length == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (hurdles != null || hurdles.Length >= 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < hurdles.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                max = max < hurdles[i+1] ? hurdles[i+1] : max;
            }
            if (jumpHeight >= max)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
            return false;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(hurdleJump(new int[] {}, 7));
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an IndexOutOfRangeException / ArgumentOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-an-indexoutofrangeexception-argumentoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-f)

Comment: `if (hurdles == null && hurdles.Length == 0)` should be `if (hurdles == null || hurdles.Length == 0)` Currently, you'll get a `NullReferenceException` if `hurdles` is null. Then you won't need the check against null in the `else if` condition.

Comment: Also, you need to move the `int max = hurdles[0]` into the `else if` body. Have a think about why this is necessary.

Comment: you also could use the Any() method, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: `hurdels[0]` accesses the **first** element, while you provide an **empty** one. Simply omit that line.

Answer (score 1):

1. Moved the max initialization to after we've ensured handles is not null or empty.
2. Changed the first && to an ||.

   ```
    public static bool hurdleJump(int[] hurdles, int jumpHeight)
    {
        if (hurdles == null || hurdles.Length == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            int max = hurdles[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < hurdles.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                max = max < hurdles[i + 1] ? hurdles[i + 1] : max;
            }
            if (jumpHeight >= max)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
   ```

Comment: In the "else" you don't need to re-check the condition of the "if". You already know it isn't true